# How to create new resource from a file via CKAN API with cURL?

Tags: api, curl, ckan

The following cURL is from: https://tech.datopian.com/ckan/play-around.html#create-organizations-datasets-and-resources
and lets you add a resource to a datset from a url.

curl -X POST http://ckan:5000/api/3/action/resource_create -H "Authorization: 9c04a69d-79f4-4b4b-b4e1-f2ac31ed961c" -d '{
"package_id": "my-first-dataset",
"url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frictionlessdata/test-data/master/files/csv/100kb.csv",
"description": "This is the best resource ever!" ,
"name": "brand-new-resource"
}'

Was wondering how you could add a resource from a file.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my example request from a Postman collection (hope it helps):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://local-ckan/api/3/action/resource_create' \
--header 'Authorization: xxx-yyy-zzz' \
--form 'package_id="dataset-name"' \
--form 'upload=@"/home/tomek/Downloads/example.csv"' \
--form 'name="new-resource-with-file"'
```

And here's a note on creating resources from my achives while I was dealing with uploading files to CKAN:

> API calls are either POST with a JSON body or POST with a multipart/form body. When using multipart/form you can't nest anything (e.g. resources) in the same call so you have to make multiple calls (package_create, resource_create, resource_create, ...). When using JSON you can't upload files as part of the same call so you need to attach any files with separate multipart/form calls e.g. with resource_patch